# Add SageMath to pylance

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, sage, pylance

I am using VSCode to write some SageMath code in a Jupyter notebook. Everything works fine and I can run my code but Pylance underlines all Sage imports and reports them as missing

I have tried adding the path (`/Applications/SageMath-9-8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sage.framework/Versions/9.8/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages`) in `Python > Analysis: Extra Paths` (which worked for python's auto-complete support) but it didn't work in this case. I am aware that I can stop Pylance from reporting missing imports altogether but this is **not** what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your question, because it helped me find where sagemath was hiding its site-packages file.

Building on this [pylance issue on github](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/58#issuecomment-812225575), I ended up adding the magic words `from sage.all import *` to the top of my `.sage` file, and then Pylance suddenly started being happy with sage builtins.

Comment: What is .sage file and where is it ??